# Monitor/poll a value in a database from a windows app when changed by a mobile app

Tags: xamarin, webapi, windows-app-sdk

So I have a windows app designed to monitor an integer value (simply 0 or 1) from my hosted database via my web api. So when a user changes this value from an android or ios app the value will be either a 0 or a 1, if it is a 1, the windows app will need to do something in my program and then change it back to a 0 to continue to monitor or poll for when this value changes again. I know I can do this through a timer and get that value every second or so but I feel there is a more efficient way to do this. Any help please?

Comment: use a database trigger

Comment: Is this database trigger done in MSQL or in an SQL query on the server? Any examples?

Comment: Your post doesn't provide any detail about the db you're using.  Google "database trigger" and your DB platform

Comment: I suspect what you are looking for is a "push notification". Research that concept and see if it is what you want.